# how to upgrade student for next year condition is only one time registration is required

Tags: fonts, center

i am doing school management system.

i have student_info table in mysql. in this i have columns as

```
student_id | student_name | student_surname | std | year and other info
```

suppose student is in 6th std of currently year.
on next year he will be in 7th std.
so how can i manage his record for next year with keeping record of current year.

> or suggest how to design database for the same.?

thanks in advance..

Comment: You have to create another table, for example:

stundent_id | std | year 

And make student_id and std the primary key

Your Register will be: 1 Name Surname and in the othen 
1 | 6th | 2013
1 | 7th | 2014